# how to add optee in barebox for imx6ul

Tags: yocto, bootloader, imx6, op-tee

I want to integrate `optee` for my imx6ul board. For that I downloaded `optee_os` and successfully compiled also I enabled optee support in kernel level using menuconfig.

Now How can I integrate `optee` support in `barebox`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below link for basic support of optee in barebox

[optee support in barebox for imx6ul](https://www.spinics.net/lists/u-boot-v2/msg30313.html)